# Tkinter: update window every n computed configurations

Tags: tkinter

I'm doing a simulation where each call of the main algorithm (which keeps computing until stop button is pressed) updates a matrix. One step takes 10ms but the refresh rate of my screen (60Hz) is less than the 100Hz needed to update the canvas in real time. Thus I would like to update the canvas every n (e.g. 3) computed configurations so that waiting for the drawing doesn't slow down the computation.

However in my main algorithm computing and drawing are coupled together, and I'm wondering how to decouple these actions. Here is my pseudocode for now:

```py
def compute():
   if running:
      #here we compute how to update the matrix ...
      pixel(matrix) #...and the corresponding pixels
   window.after(1,compute)



compute()
window.mainloop()
```

What I would like to do is (pseudocode):

```py
#HOW TO DO THE FOLLOWING PART?
while running:
  compute()
  if iteration % 3 == 0: #we want to draw only every 3 computed configurations
    redraw_canvas()
```

An example of my code is:

```py
import tkinter as tk
import numpy as np

window = tk.Tk()
window.geometry("600x600")
canv_w= 480
square_w = 8 #size of one element of the matrix
N = 60     # size of matrix
canvas=tk.Canvas(window,width=480,height=480)
canvas.pack()
my_image=tk.PhotoImage(width=480,height=480)
canvas.create_image((3, 3),image=my_image,anchor="nw",state="normal")


def pixel(matrix, i,j):

        if matrix[i,j]==-1:
            temp="#cc0000"
        elif matrix[i,j]==1:
            temp="#7CFC00"
        my_image.put(temp,to=(i*square_w,j*square_w,(i+1)*square_w,(j+1)*square_w))


def compute():
   global iteration

   div, rem = divmod(iteration, N)
   #print("I'm about to change pixel with column div and row rem)
   print(div % N, rem)
   matrix[div % N, rem]*=-1 # compute changes to the matrix (in this case we invert the colour of one pixel at each iteration)

   for i in range(N):
        for j in range(N):
            pixel(matrix,i,j) # transfer the corresponding changes to the photoimage

   iteration+=1
   window.after(1,compute)


iteration=0
running=1
matrix=np.random.choice([-1, 1], (N,N), p=[0.4,0.6])

compute()
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Since you just update one item in the matrix in each iteration, you don't need to update the whole image in each iteration.  Just update the *corresponding pixel* in each iteration instead.

Comment: @acw1668 Sorry, that was a dummy code, in reality compute does a montecarlo simulation, each iteration can change up to 100 values of the matrix

Comment: Then still just update the corresponding pixels for the changed items in the matrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just call `window.update()` after you calculated each pixel value.

```py
import tkinter as tk
import numpy as np

window = tk.Tk()
window.geometry("600x600")
canv_w= 480
square_w = 8 #size of one element of the matrix
N = 60     # size of matrix
canvas=tk.Canvas(window,width=480,height=480)
canvas.pack()
my_image=tk.PhotoImage(width=480,height=480)
canvas.create_image((3, 3),image=my_image,anchor="nw",state="normal")


def pixel(matrix, i,j):
    if matrix[i,j]==-1:
        temp="#cc0000"
    elif matrix[i,j]==1:
        temp="#7CFC00"
    my_image.put(temp,to=(i*square_w,j*square_w,(i+1)*square_w,(j+1)*square_w))

def compute():
   global iteration
   div, rem = divmod(iteration, N)
   #print("I'm about to change pixel with column div and row rem)
   print(div % N, rem)
   matrix[div % N, rem]*=-1 # compute changes to the matrix (in this case we invert the colour of one pixel at each iteration)
   for i in range(N):
        for j in range(N):
            pixel(matrix,i,j) 
        if not (i + 1) % 3:
            window.update()  # <-- added this
   window.after(1,compute)


iteration=0
running=1
matrix=np.random.choice([-1, 1], (N,N), p=[0.4,0.6])

compute()
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: sorry I think I'm missing something. Since the refresh rate is lower than the inverse of the time taken for one execution of `compute()`, I thought I should redraw the canvas every one in 2 or 3 iterations of `compute` (instead than every one), to avoid slowing down of the code due to redrawing? This answer seems to suggest I should redraw the canvas many times for each iteration of `compute`.

Comment: @we_are_always_learning  I fixed it.  Now it only updates every third iteration of the outer for loop.